# Redis Cluster with custom cluster config

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I want to create a redis cluster with only specific redis hosts being master and slave. Also I want to assign from myself which host should be replica of which master.
Currently, `cluster-create` [command](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) creates a cluster when given a list of `hostname:port` parameters in any one of the redis masters. But this does not let us provide a custom config as we require. It suggests us with what is will create, and we can approve or cancel (not edit).

Is there any simple way of achieving what I intend to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a good simple way myself.

Suppose we want to create the cluster as:

```
A1-S1 
A2-S2
A3-S3
```

Where A is master and S are their corresponding slaves and this forms a single cluster. The steps would include.

- Write into `nodes.conf` before starting the redis instances to append the desired slot hashes after the `connected` string. Make sure master and slave have the same slot hashes. Do this only for the line containing `myself`. This will look something like this:

```
Earlier:
a252d572140fd2b5410d4a63d051f1e6613cfd1f :6379@16379 myself,slave 0 0 0 connected

Final:
a252d572140fd2b5410d4a63d051f1e6613cfd1f :6379@16379 myself,slave 0 0 0 connected 0-5500
```

After this start the redis instances.

- Now one by one do a cluster meet for each pair of master and slave. Do 3 `cluster meet` each for A1, A2 and A3 for their corresponding slaves. This connects the master and slave.
- If by chance the master becomes a slave after a meet operation, do a `cluster failover` from the slave to make it the master.
- Finally, run 2 more `cluster meet` for A1-A2 and A2-A3.

Doing this you get a cluster of the config you need.